# How to directly draw circles and arcs?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using the Autodesk Forge Viewer v7 and I'm using the Edit2D tools on an AutoCAD drawing (converted to svf of course).  I see the polygon and polyline tools, and if I allow arcs on those I can go back after creation and turn something into an arc, but is there a tool to allow the user to just directly draw a circle or arc?  Seems pretty basic but I don't see it anywhere...

I have been looking at [this tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/edit2d-use/) but it only lists the 4 tools.  Certainly there are more available tools or options?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can only create arcs on existing shapes. If there is a reasonable demand for this kind of feature (for example, introducing a "clutch key" that would immediately place an arc instead of a straight line), we would be happy to suggest this to the viewer engineering team as a new feature.

Comment: Ok.  We can probably make it work as is but it seems like it would be a much better UX if we could make it switch to an arc drawing mode in process (your "clutch key"). Put my vote down for the new feature.